# Making the webpage RESPONSIVE to all resolutions

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a [webpage](http://mediaup-pages.com/yesminisite/) that has a simple form and background image.

The page doesn't react well to different screen resolutions i.e. its not responsive.

Here's a [Screenfly](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//mediaup-pages.com/yesminisite/&w=1024&h=768&a=1) of the page to see the issue

how can i make this web page responsive and fit all screens?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      yes Landing Page
    </title>
    <link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="form/stylesform.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
        <img id="shadow" src="images/shadow.png"/>
        <div id="bg"><img id="bg2" src="images/bgBig.png"/></div>


        <div id="ul1">
          <img src="images/join.png"/>
          <!--<img id="shadow" src="shadow.png"/>-->


          <form name="contactform" class="contact_form" method="post" name="contact_form" action="contactengine.php">
              <ul>
                  <li>
                      <label for="name"></label>
                      <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="name" required />
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="telephone">
                    <li class="telephone">
                        <label class="telephone" for="telephone"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="Tel" class="telephone" placeholder="phone" required />
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                  <button id="send "type="submit" name="submit1"><img src="images/submit.png"></button>
            </form>
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#content{

}
#shadow {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 1920px;
  height: 397px;
  margin-top: 803px;
  margin-left: 0;
  z-index: 11;
}

#bg {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 1920px;
  height: 841px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: -1920px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #2f3a42;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(28,40,46,1) 0%, rgba(113,127,141,1) 100%),-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(28,40,46,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(113,127,141,1))),-webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(28,40,46,1) 0%,rgba(113,127,141,1) 100%),-ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(28,40,46,1) 0%,rgba(113,127,141,1) 100%),linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(28,40,46,1) 0%,rgba(113,127,141,1) 100%);
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FF1C282E',endColorstr='#FF717F8D',GradientType=0)";
}

#form {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 591px;
  height: 323px;
  margin-top: 473px;
  margin-left: -1562px;
  z-index: 41;
}



#ul1 {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 238px;
  margin-top: 487px;
  margin-left: -1342px;
  z-index: 45;
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: you should use bootrap or change width in percentage instead of pixel

Answer (score 1):

You will need to include various MEDIA **QUERIES / BREAK-POINTS** for specific screen sizes.

E.g. -

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}
/**********
iPad 3
**********/
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}
/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen  and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen  and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 5 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 568px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 568px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 6 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-height: 667px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-height: 667px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 6+ ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-height: 736px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-height: 736px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* Samsung Galaxy S3 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* Samsung Galaxy S4 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}

/* Samsung Galaxy S5 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 360px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 360px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}
```

You may include as many screen sizes as you want. For more information you may please refer - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Though you can manage the responsive nature of web page without it but using `Media Queries or Break-Points` is always the best practice and most recommended option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
@media (max-width: 1920px) and (min-width: 1080px) {
  @viewport {
   //here you can edit your layout for that resolution
  }
}
```

for each resolution use different `max-width` and `min-width` and different settings inside css.

Answer (score 0):

You may try [developers.google tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/use-media-queries?hl=en) which gives really a good knowledge of webpage responsiveness.

OR,
You may us [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) which is a really good framework for making responsive webpages.

Answer (score 0):

For making a perfect responsive page with this design, some more slicing is to be done with the image.

For now, with the current html page, please try the below.

```
#content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
}
```

Also add meta tag for devices in `<head>`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```